# Is there a way to retrieve the displayed value of a pressed key in keyboard event

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I would like to let the user press a combination of keys and display the input in a readable way.
If the the pressed for example <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> I would like to display `alt P`.

I know how to handle the modifier keys themselves but I couldn't find a solution for the "normal" keys. I tried to use the `event.code` property which gives me in this case `KeyP` (The `event.key` or `event.which` properties are not suitable as the modifier keys would change the value to eg `π`).
But I would have to map the value of `event.code` to `P`, especially for keys with special characters as they might have very different values on different layouts.

Is there a property to retrieve the displayed value of a key (the value printed on the physical keyboard without modifiers!) or a library to map the `event.code` to the displayed value for the most common keyboard layouts?
(Eg `event.code = "Quote"` mapped to `Quote`/`"` for American layout and to `Ä` for German layout)

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
    document.getElementById("keydownResult").innerText = event.code + " pressed. Value is " + event.key + ".";
    // Procduces "KeyP pressed. Value is π." on macOS with german layout.
  });
};
```

```html
<p id="keydownResult"></p>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I added an example.

Comment: I wonder if this might be what your looking for -> https://medihack.github.io/keycuts/

Comment: On Windows the **AltGr** + (some key) key produces what you're experiencing on MAC with the Alt + (some key)- if anyone willing to test this on Windows.