# Get the value of the key that was pressed before it was modified by modifier keys

Tags: javascript, keyboard, keyboard-events

Inside a `keydown` event I want to be able to retrieve the value of the key that was pressed as if no modifier keys were used. So for example, the `1` key on my keyboard can also type a `!` character if I hold `shift` while pressing it. So pressing `1` comes out to `1` but pressing `shift + 1` comes out to `!`

Is there some way I can make `shift + 1` equate to `1` inside my `keydown` handler? I want to do this because I'm making a Sudoku game where users can toggle candidates on and off inside the cells by hovering over the cell and pressing a number key. But sometimes, the user doesn't want to *toggle* the candidate, but rather they want to simply turn it off. If it's off, leave it off, if it's on, turn it off.

I want to allow users to hold `shift` while pressing number keys to perform this behavior. So `shift + 8` will turn off the "8" candidate for that cell. But `shift + 8` is recorded as `*`, and because of that I have no way of knowing what number they pressed.

Is there any way to get the value of the key that was pressed as if it wasn't modified by modifier keys? So that `shift + 8` comes out to `8` instead of `*`?

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62552959/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-displayed-value-of-a-pressed-key-in-keyboard-even) from 33 months ago, but it has no answers.

I considered using `KeyboardEvent.code` in combination with `Keyboard.getLayoutMap()`, but that currently has atrocious browser support with [MDN saying that it's not supported on even the latest versions of Firefox or Safari.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Keyboard/getLayoutMap#browser_compatibility) (And it doesn't look like that's going to change any time soon, as it's been 5 years since all other popular browsers started supporting it.)

Is there any known way to do this or am I entirely out of luck here? I could always fall back onto the option of using a different key instead of `shift` to perform this action, but `shift` is definitely the most intuitive.

Comment: Why do you need `Keyboard.getLayoutMap()`? Can't you just check `event.code`?

Comment: I'm concerned that different keyboard layouts will bind different values to those keys. I don't want to respond to the user pressing whatever key is named `Digit1`, I want to respond to the user inputting the digit `1`, no matter what key it's inputted with.

Answer (score 0):

For digits only we can use `event.code` in `keydown` event to detect what number the pressed key represents (i.e. `Digit5` or `Numpad7`) Once we detected that we can stop the event and add the number into the input field:

```js
test.addEventListener("keydown", e =>
{
  // uncomment line below to allow use SHIFT + NUMPAD* as arrow keys
//  if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey)
  {
    const key = (e.code.match(/^[A-Za-z]{2,}(\d)$/)||[])[1];
    if (key && e.key != key)
    {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      const input = e.target,
            selectionStart = input.selectionStart,
            selectionEnd = input.selectionEnd;
      //insert key
      input.value = input.value.substring(0, selectionStart)
        + key
        + input.value.substring(selectionEnd);
      //restore cursor position
      input.selectionStart = selectionStart + key.length;
      input.selectionEnd = input.selectionStart;
    }
    return;
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="test">
```

Comment: What about keys other than numbers? This (ignoring a few edge cases) allows me to successfully implement what I want with my Sudoku game, but it still doesn't answer the underlying question of "How to get the value of a key before modifier keys?"